# After upgrading to Xampp 1.8.1, can't view my sites

Tags: joomla, xampp, upgrade

I was using xampp 1.7.0 but just decided to upgrade to xampp 1.8.1. I uninstalled the 1.7 but didn't uninstall the htdocs and mysql server.
I now installed 1.8 and create passwords for the xampp directory and mysql through the xampp security page.
Unfortunately, I can't view my sites again, they all give errors, this is a sample error:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\3nity\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 29
Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\3nity\libraries\loader.php on line 71
Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\3nity\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 32
Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\3nity\libraries\loader.php on line 71
Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\3nity\libraries\loader.php on line 138
Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::clean() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\3nity\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 33
Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\3nity\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 463
```

Please what can I do because i don't have a backup of all the sites, 5 years of hard work with a current clients project at hand now.

I use a win 7 operating system 64bit, used xampp-win32-1.8.1-VC9-installer.

Comment: should be moved to http://serverfault.com

Comment: What about updating Joomla to the latest version? `Do a backup before! (even if it is not working now!)` Last chance: Downgrade back to 1.7.0

Comment: my joomla was the latest version before i upgraded my xampp.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely due to a different (newer) version of PHP in the latest XAMPP. PHP 5.4 (PHP 5.4.7 to be exact) is more strict about warning for bad code.

The real problem is in the actual PHP code (either yours or code used in a package use use, like Joomla).

If it is coming from your code, you should fix it. Do so by accessing a static method property or property in a static way (e.g. `class Foo { public static $bar = 123; }` and `Foo::$bar` to access it, and `class Bar { public static function foo() { } }` and `Bar::foo()` to invoke it. Note how we use `::` instead of `->`. This means there is no active instantiation state. In other words, `$bar = new Bar(); $bar->foo();` is incorrect as it calls it as a instance method instead of statically through `Bar::foo()`.

Likewise, if the problem is the other way around, the developer may have to declare a method as `static` if it is stateless and called statically.

For the Joomla case it seems there are various reports about it already:

- http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=271244
- http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=182516
- http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=166802

(Found by pasting the error in Google!)

Learn more about the difference between state and static:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php
- [http://phpduck.com/php-static-methods-and-properties/](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626152457/http://phpduck.com/php-static-methods-and-properties/) (archived)

If you only have warnings (not errors), learn about `error_reporting` and disable these innocent warnings (by lowering the error reporting level). That way you reduce the noise and can focus on other things.

During development you should probably not hide any warnings and so that you can spot them and improve your code. But in production it may be better to hide the warnings and only log errors.

Comment: i'm sorry if this sounds stupid, i no nothing about programming, just a web designer. where can i get that- "php error_reporting"

Comment: First make sure you are using the latest versions of your software as well (update Joomla, plugins therein etc. and make backups first of course!). If you are still getting warnings or if there are problems with newer versions of Joomla, then consider changing the `error_reporting` setting in your `php.ini` configuration. Learn how by googling it. It's better to find out yourself from good documentation, you'll learn something along the way! I've given enough pointers I think.

Comment: I have edited the php.ini, i set the error reporting to ALL but it still shows the error.

Comment: After editing php.ini, my joomla 2.5 sites do not give errors again while my joomla 1.5 sites still give errors. And the most scary part is that am now seeing another error: 'Database connection error (3): Could not connect to database'

Answer (score 0):

After going through all the information and links presented, I was able to overcome the strict standard issue. The changes I made earlier didn't reflect because I was changing the values at the wrong line.
This is what I did:
I had to edit line 535 & 552 of my php.ini file and set display errors to OFF and also used this setting: error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE.
Both Joomla 1.5 and 2.5 sites don't give errors again.
Thanks to everybody.

Comment: The only problem now is that I couldn't restore my database through mysql ibdata01 file, I didn't backup before I uninstalled xampp 1.8. Would appreciate if you can give a step by step details of how to restore my database through these files: ibdata01, ib_logfile1, ib_logfile0. Those are the only files I found in the mysql data folder.